why am I getting: Error reading from remote server returned by /examples/
I am trying to configure Tomcat to work with Apache2 in a Ubuntu Server 24.04. I managed so far to install correctly Apache2: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) and Tomcat: Apache Tomcat/10.1.24.
Both run fine - Tomcat run under http://server_ip_address:8080.
My problem is this:  I am trying to request one of the example files that Tomcat should serve up by pointing the browser to http://server_ip_address/examples/ but without success.
Getting this:

So I checked the log and I found:
[Fri May 31 07:55:23.746796 2024] [core:notice] [pid 3664] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri May 31 07:55:28.326763 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3666] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client my_pc_addr:60293] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server server_ip_address:8009
[Fri May 31 07:55:28.326809 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 3666] [client my_pc_addr:60293] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /examples/
[Fri May 31 07:55:30.298981 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3666] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client my_pc_addr:60293] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server server_ip_address:8009
[Fri May 31 07:55:30.304898 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3667] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client my_pc_addr:60294] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server server_ip_address:8009
[Fri May 31 07:55:30.304955 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 3667] [client my_pc_addr:60294] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /examples/

I configured Apache like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  JkMount /examples worker1
  JkMount /examples/* worker1
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://server_ip_address:8009/ Keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://server server_ip_address:8009/
  RequestHeader set X-Forward-Proto "http"
  RequestHeader set X-Forward-Port "80"
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

The AJP1.3 service:
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               port="8009"
               address="server_ip_address"
               secretRequired="true"
               secret="ThisIsATest!"
               allowedRequestAttributesPattern="AJP_Local_ADDR"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               maxThreads="300"
               minSpareThreads="10"
               enableLookups="false"
               tcpNoDelay="true"
               tomcatAuthentication="false"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               />

and the HTTP Connector:
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               address="server_ip_address"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />

I am open to all suggestions and help to solve this. Just for info I tried to resolve this now i two days!! Any help is very appreciate.
